# Error displaying a user's name and user's avatar who is associated with a comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, comments, model-associations

With the code below...

```
<%= image_tag comment.user.avatar.url(:medium), class: "circle-extrasmall" %>
<%= comment.user.name %>
```

I get the error...

```
undefined method `avatar' for nil:NilClass
```

I think I've created the right associations for users and comments.

Here's what is in the controller...

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

def create
@challenge = Challenge.find(params[:challenge_id])
@comment = @challenge.comments.create(params[:comment])
@comment.user_id = current_user
flash[:notice] = "Comment has been created!"
redirect_to @challenge
end

end
```

and here's what is in the model...

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :challenge_id, :user_id, :text

validates :user_id, presence: true

belongs_to :challenge
belongs_to :user
end
```

But, I'm not sure what is causing that error. I'm new to Ruby-on-Rails. Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pleas change the create action code

```
@comment = @challenge.comments.new(params[:comment])
@comment.user_id = current_user.id
@comment.save
```

As you already have some records which don't have user_id. So you need to remove those record or for now you can do like the followings to get rid of this error

```
<% comment_user = comment.user%>
<%= image_tag comment_user.avatar.url(:medium), class: "circle-extrasmall" unless comment_user.blank?%>
<%= comment_user.name unless comment_user.blank?%>
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error...

    undefined method `avatar' for nil:NilClass

Comment: yes that is because you have some records in your database which do not have user_id. So delete those record or you can have <%= image_tag comment.user.avatar.url(:medium), class: "circle-extrasmall" unless comment.user.blank?%>
<%= comment.user.name unless comment.user.blank? %>

Comment: Okay, I'm not getting the nil error anymore. But, it's still not showing the user name or avatar. I don't think the user_id is being added to the comment when the comment is being created.

With the validates :user_id, presence: true in the model, it doesn't allow me to post a comment, meaning it isn't recognizing the current_user_id I guess. Any ideas?

Comment: I also ran a migration AddUserIdToComments a while back, so it appears the user_id is included in the table as an integer.

I don't know why it won't recognize it.

Comment: @Ethan, I am also surprised with this behaviour of your application. umm.. Can you please delete all the records from the comments and try to create the new record with my code. I have modified the action code..

Answer (score 1):

As per your error the user is not saving for the `comment`. So it shows the error for `comment.user.avatar` . When user object is nil you can't get its `avatar` value.

In your code create method `comment.user` should be the `current_user`

You can edit the create method like

```
def create

@challenge = Challenge.find(params[:challenge_id])
@comment = @challenge.comments.build(params[:comment])
@comment.user = current_user

@comment.save
flash[:notice] = "Comment has been created!"
redirect_to @challenge
end
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error...

    undefined method `avatar' for nil:NilClass

Comment: did u find user_id in the comment object that you saved?

Comment: I don't think it's adding the user_id to the comment when a user creates one. Any ideas on how to do this?